# @ForeignKey with @AssociationOverride

Tags: java, jpa

Is it possible to specify the name of the foreign key in case of overriding a relationship?

I tried the following:

```
@AssociationOverride(name = "client", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "client_idx", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_TEST")) })
```

The joined column is correctly named client_idx, but the foreign key name is generated by the system.

I would like to set the foreign key name by myself.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want the `foreignKey` element to be specified on the `AssociationOverride` annotation (not the embedded `JoinColumn` annotation), like this:

```
@AssociationOverride(
    name = "client",
    joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "client_idx")
    },
    foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_TEST")
)
```

UPDATE: See comment below from bikeshedder.

Comment: I think your solution is "correct" but does not work because of a hibernate bug that was never fixed. See https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-4329 -- sadly the issue was closed but still exists for the `javax.persistence` annotations.

Comment: There seems to be a new bug report about this: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10387