# JPA: Setting @ForeignKey name in @MappedSuperclass

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I am using Hibernate 6.1.2 as JPA implementation to connect from Java 17 to PostgreSQL 12+.

I have a `@MappedSuperclass` to track changes with something like this:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "modification_users_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name="fk_problem_is_here"), nullable = false)
private User modificationUser;
```

The user is a backend user stored in another table users and not a PostgreSQL user. That was necessary for session handling, data sharing, and other things. It was a several month analysis and negotiation with customers to finalize that, I cannot make many changes there.

My problem is that whatever I put as foreign key name is used for every `@Entity` class that inherits from my `@MappedSuperclass`. The PostgresSQL server actually accepts that, but it is most likely not valid according to SQL-99. Moreover, external tools like pgmodeler get utterly confused during import. Finally, it is not coherent to what we specified for foreign key nomenclature internally.

Many questions showing up on the web are about corresponding `@OneToMany` attributes in classes that would corresponding to my `Users` class. However, that might not be a problem here because there are currently no plans to search all modifications done by one user with the Java backend. Thus, I thin I can just omit those attributes in the class.

I found something that seems to be related [here](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=987384). However, the discussion goes into a direction that seems to be about Oracle automatic constraint generation and is not something that related to how to do it in Java.

At the moment, my last and best hope for a solution seems to be Copy&Paste the attribute with minimal changes for every derived `@Entity` class. What I would prefer is only changing the annotation in the derived classes, putting as little Copy&Paste code there as possible. Can this be done?

Edit: based on replies I considered a solution like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30785192/foreignkey-with-associationoverride) but there still seems to be a Hibernate bug. I have troubles understanding the bug report discussion, but if I add

```
@AssociationOverride(name = "modificationUser", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "modification_users_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name="fk_inventories_users_id"), nullable = false)})
```

to the derived class I can actually change the name of the foreign key, but only from the preset in the `@MappedSuperclass` to gibberish, as if I had not set a key name at all.

Comment: What happens if you simply don't set `foreignKey` in the parent class?

Comment: I think you are looking for the `@AssociationOverride` annotation ([ref](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/persistence/AssociationOverride.html)). Specify it in the subclasses; the example in the Javadocs seems to fit your case very closely.

Comment: I need to set something, otherwise I get names like `fkmaxnxnbv09bbuu4kb0yjg6i8` which is not a solution I can live with. I will now check `@AssociationOverride`. I have already used it for something different, but I do not have enough experience to do it without further research.

Comment: I tried to do it with `@AssociationOverride` but if failed. I have added the results to the original post.

Comment: Looks like https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-4329 is not out of date. You should create a new JIRA issue and reference that.

Answer (score 1):

The `@AssosiationOverride` annotation has a specific parameter for the foreign key name. It should work if you redefine the foreign key directly in `@AssosiationOverride` and not inside `@JoinColumn`.

`@AssociationOverride(name = "modificationUser", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "modification_users_id", nullable = false), foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name="fk_inventories_users_id")})`

I only validated this with Hibernate version 6.2.5, which uses the jakarta namespaces. I don't know if this works for older versions.

Comment: had a problem where i couldn't override the fk name of an embeded class.
your hint solved that issue.
... also working for hibernate 5.6.15